# How much does Enterprise Architect support OCL language?

Tags: enterprise-architect, ocl, mdd

http://wp13117963.server-he.de/blog/2007/01/15/ocl-support-in-enterprise-architect/comment-page-1/#comment-2035

I am facing an issue mentioned in the above article. i.e. Enterprise Architect is not giving any error when I create a constraint on an attribute with wrong syntax.

Comment: Please include all relevant info in the question itself, and make sure to clearly indicate your actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: it fakes OCL. EA is doing no syntax check of OCL itself. In no way does it execute OCL and will not do any constraint checking. You can only mark a constraint as being OCL:

[image]

That's it. Just try to enter an inalid constraint and EA will swallow it with no warning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I can come to the conclusion that EA has almost zero support for OCL. Following that, have you personally used any good tools which supports OCL? I want to generate code with behavior using UML and OCL.

Comment: Yes, that conclusion is correct. I once tried a tool from (IIRC) Universität Dresden. My feeling is that OCL is merely used in academic circles. Using UML in the industry is more rare than often. OCL is even more rarely applied. There might be industrial OCL applicaitions but I have not come in touch with any.

Comment: I now looked into the blog entry you referenced. Exactly. Just what I have experienced.

Comment: Just google for "OCL Dresden" and you find the references. It's also on github.